# How to get image from C# method in as3(flash)?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, sockets, actionscript, c#-3.0

For my project I want to view a live webcam feed captured in C# into a **as3 flash application** over sockets.

I have a **c# bitmap image** which I'm **sending over socket**.
Now i want to receive this bitmap image in as3 flash application to show.

Comment: So what have you tried and what doesn't work with that solution?

Comment: In which step are you stuck?  
 1. Creating a new socket and connecting to the C# host.
 2. Transferring the binary data.
 3. Converting the data to a bitmap.
 4. Displaying the bitmap.

Comment: Hi, I am able to create socket in C#. Then i have converted the image into Byte array and then i have send over socket. I am unable to receive it in as3.

Comment: make sure Your AS3 socket is connected and receive any data (with progress event) , than raw bitmap can be loaded to bitmapdata by setPixels() or looping setPixel function

Comment: I have tried it and i am able to connect through socket. But the problem is i get the size of bytearray received is 65536 (MAX) while the size of bitmap is more. I have tried using a buffer also but still not working. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide the code (client and server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to figure out.

This code Captures live webcam feed from c# and send it to AS3(Flash) Application.

**I am sending image from c# :**

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Bitmap t = image.Clone(r, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    t.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] imageBuffer = ms.ToArray();
                    byte[] filesize = BitConverter.GetBytes(imageBuffer.Length);
                    byte[] msg = new byte[filesize.Length + imageBuffer.Length];
                    filesize.CopyTo(msg, 0);
                    imageBuffer.CopyTo(msg, 4);
                    netstream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    t.Dispose();

                }
```

**And in the AS3 Side i m receiving it as :**

```
socket.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
b.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;// Changing it to little endian worked.
socket = new Socket();          
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 12345);

private function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void 
{   
......
socket.readBytes(b,0,4);
b.position = 0;
filesize = b.readInt();
b.clear();
socket.readBytes(b,0,socket.bytesAvailable);
b.position = 0;         
l = new Loader();
l.loadBytes(b); 
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
}

private function loaded(e:Event):void
{
    var bitmap:Bitmap = e.target.content;
    while(this.numChildren > 0)
    {
        this.removeChildAt(0);
    }           
    addChild(bitmap);
    // remove listener
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
}
```

Comment: how much fps are you getting ?   i would suggest using only one instance of bitmap in flash and update its bitmapdata to avoid adding and removing from the display stack